# ubuntu stuck at 'pls remove installation media and close tray and press enter

Tags: system-installation

i tried to install ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my dell inspiron 5520 alongside windows 7 64 bit. It showed up a message like 'remove any installation media and close the tray if any and press enter'. When i did the above said job windows started up as usual

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/529264/ubuntu-stuck-at-please-remove-installation-media-and-close-tray-and-press-enter

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the you didn't install a bootloader that knows about your Ubuntu installation. So Windows just boots like normal. Easiest way is to install again and this time install the bootloader (Grub2) when prompted.

During Grubs installation it will scan your drives and make a list of options to boot into when you reboot.

Comment: i am not a computer geek, i don't know what a boot loader is. but i could choose boot options on my laptop to install ubuntu from a bootable cd by pressing f12. some battery checking takes place and later comes this problem. Surprisingly i found wubi in the start up folder of windows. It is working like windows installer.

Comment: A boot loader is essentially a menu of the systems installed on your machine. When you choose one, it boots it. 
If you are using Wubi then its slightly different, your Windows installation should prompt you to boot into Ubuntu if its installed correctly. Its not the same as a normal Ubuntu installation and there are tons of docs available in the Wubi help pages to get you going.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your intrest in answering my qyestion.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in the following way:

1. once prompted to remove dvd and close the tray and press enter, do it without any delay.
2. now your system starts with windows automatically, if not you start your system.
3. wait for all windows services to start.
4. now go to startup folder, you will find wubi there.
5. click on it and follow the instructions ubuntu gets installed.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem while installing Ubuntu 14.04, so I did this:

1. My disk partitions were NTFS, so I created unallocated space using GParted (from the Ubuntu LiveCD).
2. Make sure you create enough unallocated space.

After this install Ubuntu. Problem will be solved

Comment: Vishal: "Do, or do not!  There is no try" (look up the quote) (and also review my [edit]s and also read the editing help)  ;-)